# Bundling Assets Outside of src Root flet/pyinstaller

Tags: python, pyinstaller, flet

I have a Flat project with the structure:

```
root/
  resources/
    assets/
      image.png
  src/
    gui.py
```

```py
# gui.py
import pathlib

import flet as ft


ROOT = pathlib.Path(".") / ".."
ASSETS_DIR = str((ROOT / "resources" / "assets"))


def main(page: ft.Page):
    page.title = ASSETS_DIR
    img = ft.Image(
        src="image.png",
        width=100,
        height=100,
        fit=ft.ImageFit.SCALE_DOWN,
    )
    page.add(img)
    page.update()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    ft.app(target=main, assets_dir=ASSETS_DIR)
```

This works when running the project locally (the image is displayed).

However, if I try to package the application with `flet pack src/main.py --add-data "resources/assets/*:resources/assets"` the image does not resolve. (Uses Pyinstaller under the hood setting the spec files `Analysis.datas` to `[('resources/assets/*', 'resources/assets')]`).

I've been able to make this work if the assets folder is at the same level as, or below the `gui/.py` file in the project structure, but I was wondering if there's a way to allow me to have my assets separate from my source code.

Thanks